# Forcing HTTPS on Apache with strange results

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite

I just bought an SSL cert for my site and I am trying to force HTTPS. It kinda works but not really. I am on Apache using PHP Slim framework for custom routing.

My folder struct

```
root/
   .htaccess (A)
   php/
   public_html/
     .htaccess (B)
```

**.htaccess (A)**

My main htaccess file has these rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I go to `example.com` it goes to the secure page. Great!

**.htaccess (B)**

My public_html file has these rules

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>


# Always use https for secure connections
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Problem:**

If I go to http://www.example.com/login,

instead of redirected to https://www.example.com/login,

it redirects to https://www.example.com/index.php

Comment: That's because you have _two_ sets of rules in your htaccess. The first rule, inside the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`, checks if the requested file exists, and if it doesn't, redirect to `index.php`. Since `/login` probably don't exist as a real file, that rule will get triggered. Simply move your https-check _before_ the other rule.

Comment: Added it as an answer, so you can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rules in htaccess-files get's validate from top to bottom. In your htaccess, it first check if the requested resource (/login) exists on the server or not. If it doesn't, it redirects the request to index.php.

It should work if you simply moved the https-check/redirect *before* the other rule.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteBase /

    # Always use https for secure connections
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Redirect requests to non existing resources to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I also removed the second `RewriteEngine On`. Having it once is enough.